# How do I calculate order profit

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

How do I ensure the profit column in the magento standard order report deducts the product cost from the order.   I have entered cost price information in the catalog but the profit figure being displayed is the same as the revenue figure

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2?